# wordpress How to get the user_id column from wp_usermeta

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to associate the wp_metadata with the column user_id in wp_metadata

How would you get the (user_id column) from wp_usermeta? I'm writing a csv function to get a few db joins out of the database. So far I've had success with getting that part of the data out, but no luck with getting the metadatas associated id in the loop:

```
foreach($all_auctions as $single_auction){

$meta = get_user_meta( $user_id );
$row['phone'] = get_user_meta($meta->user_id , 'ua_user_phno', true );

$row['address'] = get_user_meta(  $single_auction->user_id 'ua_user_street_add', true ); 

}

$data_array[]=$row;
```

Comment: what eror you getting.can you print $row and put here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$meta = get_user_meta( $user_id );`

should already contain all the meta data for that user. You should be able to access ua_user_phno as `$meta[ua_user_phno][0]`.

There's a comma missing after the user id in your statement for the address. Also, if $single_auction is a post object, it would probably be $single_auction->post_author, not $single_auction->user_id.

And lastly: `$data_array[]=$row;` should go inside the loop, or you'll only get the last row.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated for the above, i am able to get the user_meta displaying if i hard code the id in, it is accessing the user_id column itself in the wp_usermeta that seems to be non accessible via get_user_meta, unless i write a sql query it does not seem accessible what im trying to achieve is getting the user_id within a loop through the array and associate the correct user_id to the its meta value.

Comment: Are you trying to get the user id of the current user or of the author of a post?

Comment: Im trying to get the user_id from the db column basically the users id whom owns the data , defiantly not the current_user logged in user,  im after getting each individual users metadata via there user_id in the metadata table.

Comment: $single_auction is a post object, right? In that case, its' owner should be $single_auction->post_author. 
If you want to loop over all users, use `get_users()`, the ID will be in $user->ID.

Comment: single_auction is the post object but that returns winners data unfortunately this doesn't include the metadata or id of the user, the author of the post would return the posts author not the users id , ive tried a bazillion combinations at a bit of a wall think its more than likely the way the arrays are being accessed within 3 for-each loops.

Comment: have you looked at what else $single_auction contains? `var_export($single_auction);` and look for the user id you're expecting. Also, look at the meta data for $single_auction, maybe it's in a custom field.

Comment: var_export was spot on the nail thanks , this allowed me to truly see what was being outputted, there was no id being passed through a from a few objects and loops in the code, a quick inner join and temp column and heypresto! the data became available thankyou for your support janh2